# Trouble bringing in a string with d-MMM-yy format parse.exact to date but keeping date format and date type for sorting

Tags: c#, string, parsing, date, format

As the title said I am bringing in a date string from a datatable with the format of "d-MMM-yy" or 27-AUG-06.

I need to convert it to a date type for sorting, but I need to keep the same format for display.

NOTE: I am using C#, .Net 2.0, and I am retyping this code so bear with me on typos

```
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi;
dtfi = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
dtfi.ShortDatePattern = "d-MMM-yy";
dtfi.DateSeperator = "-";

//this is in a for loop with rowCnt being the row index/counter: loop and datatable is working fine. 
//"newRow" represents a DataRow in the new table.
// the table [row] [column] is bringing in the string date like "27-AUG-06"
//colXDate IS RECORDED AS {8/27/2006 12:00:00 AM}
DateTime colXDate = DateTime.ParseExact(inputDataTable.Rows[rowCnt]["colX"].ToString(), "d-MMM-yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

//@@@@ THIS NEXT LINE IS WHERE IT GIVES ME AN ERROR "String was not recognized as valid datetime."
newRow["colX"] = Convert.ToDateTime(colXDate.ToString(), dtfi);
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCENARIO: I am passing a datatable back as a DataGrids datasource. I am passing in a string field that is a date. I want to convert it to a date so that I can sort by it but I also want to maintain the same format that it was on the string that came in.

ISSUE: From some of my research it seems that the DateTime type is exactly that a datatype in whatever datatable that you put it in and is not formatable. So even though I bring in an unormal string date and convert it to a datetime via the DateTime.ParseExact, when I put it into my datetime field and try to format it (newRow["colX"] = colXDate.ToString("d-MMM-yy"); //as Scott had above) it still goes in as a set datetime format with hours...etc.

SOLUTION: So I resolved this by smoke and mirrors. I put 2 columns in the datatable, the first being the string format display date and the second the datetime type. On ItemDataBound I hid the datetime column (e.Item.Cells[5].Visible = false;) and then on the sort event I test for string date column (e.SortExpression == "colX") and if it is true I sort by the hidden datetime column.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have colXDate as a DateTime, you don't need to convert it to a string and then back into a datetime.
Instead, try this:

```
newRow["colX"] = colXDate.ToString("d-MMM-yy");
```

Comment: There's a lot of needless `ToString` followed by parsing going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Your line fails because `ToString()` will output the date in the format defined in the current culture and you are trying to convert it back to a date using your custom date format.

You need to set it to `colXDate.ToString("d-MMM-yy")`.

Comment: thank you things are working as far as the data but the format is still off. I think it is because newRow["colX"] column is defined as datetime type so when I do newRow["colX"] = colXDate.ToString("d-MMM-yy"); It displays as 8/27/2006 12:00:00 AM. Is there any way when I add my column {dtbl.Columns.Add("colX", typeof(DateTime));} or after to get it in the desired format "d-MMM-yy" while still keeping the datetime data type?

Comment: From some of my research it seems that the DateTime type is what it is in a datatable and unformatble. I am passing this datatable back as a DataGrids datasource. So I think I can do this by smoke and mirrors. If I put 2 columns in the datatable, the first being the string format display date and the second the datetime type. On ItemDataBind I hide the datetime column and then on the sort I test for string date column and if it is true I sort by the hidden datetime column.